# Standard error log in Gulp Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gulp, babeljs

With this task:

```
gulp.task("es6", function () {
      return browserify({entries: 'src/main/es6/main.js', extensions: ['.js'], debug: true})
      .transform(babelify)
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source('superpos.js'))
      .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('src/main/webapp'));
});
```

I get this kind of error log:

[image]

It's clear and pretty, I like it.

But in order to keep my watch running, I need to handle the error instead of letting it pass, something like

```
  ...
  .transform(babelify)
  .bundle()
  .on('error', function(error){
        // pretty error print
        this.emit('end');
  })
  ...
```

How can I reproduce the same error log here?

I'd prefer to avoid painfully reproducing it by combining chalk, gutil and reading the errorring file but to use the same function somehow.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken using "watchify" instead of the Gulp watcher should be enough. You'll get the same errors, but watchify subdues the process kill

Comment: @ddprrt I tried with watchify, the watch keeps running but there's no log. I might have missed something, can you answer with a logging example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that browserify uses the [syntax-error module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/syntax-error) and thus throws rich error objects containing a console-ready `codeFrame` property.

I can intercept the error like this:

```
gulp.task("es6", function () {
      return browserify({entries: 'src/main/es6/main.js', extensions: ['.js'], debug: true})
      .transform(babelify)
      .bundle()
      .on('error', function(err){
            if (err instanceof SyntaxError) {
                  gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('Syntax Error'));
                  console.log(err.message);
                  // console.log(err.filename+":"+err.loc.line);
                  console.log(err.codeFrame);
            } else {
                  gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('Error'), err.message);
            }
            this.emit('end');
      })
      .pipe(source('superpos.js'))
      .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('src/main/webapp'));
});
```

where gutil is [gulp-util](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util)

for this result:

[image]